# How to implement a different debounce method that the function only called in the nth time

Tags: javascript, debouncing

```js
const _debounce = (n, func) => {
    //code here
}
const originFun = () => {
  console.log('hit')
}

const _call = () => _debounce(2, originFun)

_call() //The originFun not executes
_call() //hit
_call() //The originFun not executes
_call() //hit
```

I do not know how to implement it, even after a test.

Comment: `_debounce` gets `2` and a value returned by `originFun` which is undefined. It doesn't get a function in `func`. Is `_call` supposed to be like this: `const _call = (sort) => _debounce(sort, originFun)`

Comment: Thanks. The "sort" are not important, i deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation of debounce should help your use case. No global variable, and is implemented in pure javascript.

```
function _debounce(func, n){
  let count = 0;
  return (...args) => {
    count++;
    if (count % n === 0) {
        count = 0;
        func.apply(this, args);
    }
  };
}

const originFun = (sort) => {
  console.log('hit,', sort)
}

const _call = _debounce((sort) => originFun(sort), 2);

_call(1) //not execute
_call(2) //hit,2
_call(3) //not execute
_call(4) //hit,4 */
_call(1) //not execute
_call(2) //hit,2
_call(3) //not execute
_call(4) //hit,4 */
```

Comment: Wow, cool~ I knew it, thanks bro~~~~ Happy to know how to solve this problem

Comment: Nice, but this can work without apply. Arrow functions do not have any effect of apply/call/bind. Simply pass the arguments.

Comment: @TusharShahi Agreed. I can skip apply, and pass in the arguments directly. The implementation then would be:
func(...args);

Comment: @eGluZl  Do accept the answer if this solves your query. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

`_debounce` should accept the sort argument, and the `originFun` function, and return its own function (or [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)) that you can assign to `_call`. You can then call `_call` with it's own argument - the number.

```js
function originFun(sort) {
  console.log('hit,', sort);
}

function _debounce(sort, func) {

  // Set a counter
  let count = 1;

  // Because closures retain the variables from the
  // preceding lexical environment we can
  // still use and update `count` when the function is returned
  // This function (which accepts a number argument) is what's
  // assigned to _call.
  return function(n) {

    // Call originFun with the number if the remainder of dividing
    // sort by count is zero
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder
    if (count % sort === 0) func(n);
    count++;
  }
}

// _debounce returns a function that accepts a number
// argument. We assign that function to _call.
const _call = _debounce(2, originFun);

_call(1) //not execute
_call(2) //hit,2
_call(3) //not execute
_call(4) //hit,4
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep track of the number of calls you could use a global counter.

Additionally, you can pass arguments to your function using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). That way you can have multiple arguments and all of them will be passed to the function in order.

```js
let counter = 1;

const _debounce = (n, func, ...args) => {
    if (counter === n) {
        counter = 1;
        func(...args);
    } else {
        counter += 1;
    }
}

const originFun = (sort) => {
    console.log('hit,', sort)
}

const _call = (sort) => _debounce(2, originFun, sort)

_call(1) //not execute
_call(2) //hit,2
_call(3) //not execute
_call(4) //hit,4
```

Comment: Yes!! It can run. But i only can code in _debounce function. I tried it in my online test before. In my online test, i tried to use a global variables, but fail. Maybe I misunderstood the test. anyway, thanks for all.